# Missing keystrokes in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, keyboard

This has only been a problem since upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04 from 12.10.  For some reason, when typing I lose lots of keystrokes.  It doesn't seem to matter which application I'm typing in.  It happens a lot in Empathy and Firefox.

I checked the universal access settings for keyboard and they are all disabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have any clues why this is happening, but it seems to be system dependant?  My computer (dell 15r) is running quite well under ubuntu 14.04.  My wife's computer (HP dv7) is now on ubuntu 12.04 and no longer is missing keystrokes.